# PassthroughSubject not sending

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple AR application that would add a cube every time the big red button was pressed.

When button is pressed, PassthroughSubject send an enum, and it should trigger the lambda function that set through sink, which should add the cube to the scene. However, it seems that this does not happen.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import Combine

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ARViewContainer()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            Button {
                ARManager.shared.actionStream.send(.addNewBlock)
                print("Button was pressed")
            } label: {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
        }
    }
}

enum ARAction {
    case addNewBlock
    case removeAll
}

struct ARManager {
    static let shared = ARManager()
    private init() {}
    
    var actionStream = PassthroughSubject<ARAction, Never>()
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @State var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    @State private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    init() {
        subscribeToActionStream()
    }

    func subscribeToActionStream() {
        print("subscribe to action stream")
        ARManager.shared.actionStream.sink {action in
            print("Sink function was called")
            
            switch action {
            case .addNewBlock:
                print("add new block")
                addCube()
            case .removeAll:
                print("remove all")
                break
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func addCube() {
        print("addCube was called")
        // Create a cube model
        let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.1, cornerRadius: 0.005)
        let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .gray, roughness: 0.15, isMetallic: true)
        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])

        // Create horizontal plane anchor for the content
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: .any, minimumBounds: SIMD2<Float>(0.2, 0.2)))
        anchor.children.append(model)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

I can see that "subscribe to action stream" is printed out to console, which means subscribeToActionStream() is called and sink is set.

The "Button was pressed" message is also printed out, which means `ARManager.shared.actionStream.send(.addNewBlock)` line was passed.

But I did not see "Sink function was called", which indicates that PassthroughSubject never send anything.

Comment: It does get sent, but nobody is subscribed to it. Try adding ‘$’.

Comment: @cora sorry, where should I be adding $ to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work if you just put most of the things in `ARViewContainer` into a `Coordinator`, which can actually hold a strong reference to those `AnyCancellable`s.

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @MainActor
    class Coordinator {
        var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
        
        init() {
            subscribeToActionStream()
        }

        func subscribeToActionStream() {
            ...
        }
        func addCube() {
            ...
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        context.coordinator.arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
}
```

That said, I think you should also consider representing the state of the `ARView` (e.g. how many cubes there are) with your own data types, and handle adding cubes in `updateUIView`.

Here is an example, with the state of the `ARView` represented by an array of `Cube`s, identified by a `name`.

```
struct Cube {
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var cubes = [Cube]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ARViewContainer(cubes: $cubes)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            // Rather than sending things to a subject, buttons change the state of the ARView directly
            Button("Add Cube") {
                cubes.append(Cube(name: UUID().uuidString))
            }
            Button("Clear all") {
                cubes.removeAll()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var cubes: [Cube]
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        ARView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    // in updateUIView, update the ARView such that it matches the current state of the "cubes" array
    // SwiftUI calls this whenever cubes changes.
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        // a simple implementation for just handling adding cubes and clearing everything.
        // this doesn't handle removing individual cubes.
        for cube in cubes {
            if uiView.scene.findEntity(named: cube.name) == nil {
                addCube(to: uiView, name: cube.name)
            }
        }
        if cubes.isEmpty {
            uiView.scene.anchors.removeAll()
        }
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func addCube(to arView: ARView, name: String) {

        let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.1, cornerRadius: 0.005)
        let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .gray, roughness: 0.15, isMetallic: true)
        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])

        let anchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: .any, minimumBounds: SIMD2<Float>(0.2, 0.2)))
        anchor.children.append(model)
        anchor.name = name
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```